# JMImageCache in a simple test app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

In Xcode 5.0.2

1. I create [a blank single view app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/jmImage) for iPhone,
2. then add a "male.png" image to the project,
3. drag a UIImageView to the storyboard
4. and finally add the following code to the `viewDidLoad`:

   `_imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"male.png"];`

This works well:

[image]

Then I add the 4 files from [JMImageCache project](https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache) and change the [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/jmImage/jmImage/ViewController.m) to:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "JMImageCache.h"

static NSString* const kAvatar = @"http://gravatar.com/avatar/55b3816622d935e50098bb44c17663bc.png";

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAvatar]
            placeholder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"male.png"]];
}

@end
```

Unfortunately, this results in [app crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVE5Q.png) with the error message `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS`:

[image: crash]

At [his webpage](https://deallocatedobjects.com/posts/jmimagecache) Jake Marsh (the author of JMImageCache) notes:

> JMImageCache purposefully uses NSString objects instead of NSURL's to make things easier and cut down on [NSURL URLWithString:@"..."] bits everywhere. Just something to notice in case you see any strange EXC_BAD_ACCESS exceptions, make sure you're passing in NSString's and not NSURL's.

But (as an iOS programming newbie) I don't understand, what exactly does Mr. Marsh mean - since his file [UIImageView+JMImageCache.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/jmImage/jmImage/UIImageView+JMImageCache.m) declares the 1st argument for the public method as `NSURL`:

```
- (void) setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholder:(UIImage *)placeholderImage {
    [self setImageWithURL:url key:nil placeholder:placeholderImage];
}
```

Is the note maybe outdated and how could I fix my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug in JMImageCache. [`setImageWithURL:key:placeholder:completionBlock:`](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/jmImage/jmImage/UIImageView+JMImageCache.m#L55) calls itself, exhausting the stack.

To work around the bug, call the longer form of the method:

```
[_imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAvatar]
    key:nil
    placeholder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"male.png"]
    completionBlock:nil
    failureBlock:nil];
```

Or, use an older version of the library (e.g. [0.4.0](https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache/tree/0.4.0)). Looks like the bug was introduced in [1af09be78a](https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache/commit/1af09be78a04a875ff25bff6d3a323c1e719e22b).

Comment: Thanks! I've submitted a bug report: https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache/issues/33