# JMImageCache successfully installed using CocoaPods, but selector not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, cocoapods

In Xcode 5.0.2 I have [a very simple single view app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/jmImage) with an image view - which loads and displays 1 image by using JMImageCache.

This works well and has been achieved (with [the firendly help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063896/jmimagecache-in-a-simple-test-app-crashes-with-exc-bad-access) I received here at Stackoverflow) by copying 4 files (`JMImageCache.[mh]` and `UIImageView+JMImageCache.[mh]`) into my Xcode project.

Now I (an iOS programming newbie) have discovered CocoaPods and would like to use it instead.

So I have deleted those 4 files again and instead created the following [Podfile](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/jmImage/Podfile):

```
platform :ios, '5.0'
pod 'JMImageCache'
```

Then I have run:

```
# pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing JMImageCache (0.4.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] From now on use `jmImage.xcworkspace`.
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
```

and have opened jmImage.xcworkspace in Xcode.

Unfortunately now I get an error (here [the full-sized screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNpUs.png)) about a selector not being found:

[image: xcode]

Does anybody please know, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the issue: the longer method

```
 [_imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAvatar]
                         key:nil
                 placeholder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"male.png"]
             completionBlock:nil
                failureBlock:nil];
```

that I was trying to use is available in the current release of JMImageCache, but it isn't available in the JMImageCache 0.4.0 provided by CocoaPods.

I have switched to [the shorter version](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/jmImage/jmImage/ViewController.m) and now my project compiles:

```
 [_imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAvatar]
                 placeholder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"male.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your build settings search for

> Other Linker Flags

Then add

> -ObjC
>
> -all_load

Sometimes referencing Category methods from 3rd party frameworks doesn't work. I suspect that might be your issue.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your suggestion, I will keep it in mind